# Can I travel to Ukraine or Russia without a visa as a Pakistani holder of a Schengen residency permit?

Tags: pakistani-citizens, ukraine, moscow, italian-residents

I am a Pakistani with an Italian residence permit. Can I travel to Ukraine or Russia without a visa?

Answer (score 9):

No you can’t. There is no such relaxation provided by either Ukraine or Russia. You need to obtain a visa

1. [Entry regime to Ukraine for foreign citizens](http://mfa.gov.ua/en/consular-affairs/entering-ukraine/visa-requirements-for-foreigners)
2. [Russian Embassy in Pakistan](https://pakistan.mid.ru/web/pakistan_en/visa)